# Component generated greyed out and is not showing on source control

Tags: html, css, angular, visual-studio-code

[image]

Above I have generated the component and made changes.

The component is functional and running fine locally but how can I include it in the project as it seems like it is not at the moment.

I can't see it on source control to push the code changes.

Comment: do you have a .gitignore file? does it say anything about sidebar?

Comment: Hi @BenAriKutai,

I have a git ignore file but nothing is mentioned about the sidebar.

Comment: Hi @BenAriKutai, You were right, managed to solve the issue. It had the whole directory ignored for some reason but everything else was showing as normal in the project. Managed to fix it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had the whole directory ignored in the git ignore for some reason but everything else was showing as normal in the project. Managed to fix it now.